# PHP Check if variable is contained in an array

Tags: php

I have a numeric variable `$i`. This is a while loop, and `$i` increments after each iteration.

How can a conditional statement be made as to not be necessary to write such a long statement `if($i == 1 || $i == 2 || $i == 25 [...])`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are the values arbitrary, or is their inclusion governed by a mathematical equation?

Comment: create an array not a string then use in_array()

Comment: Adeneo's answer included very similar logic to Sumoanand's: both said to use `in_array()`. Sumoanand posted his first.

Comment: actully i was first :-)

Comment: okay +1 at your comm @Dagon

Comment: thank you, i just want to be loved :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use php [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php).

```
$os = array("Mac", "NT", "Irix", "Linux");
if (in_array("Irix", $os)) {
    echo "Got Irix";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems a bit obvious that you should take a deeper look at the documentation of PHP.
There is standards functions that can do a lot and help you save a lot of time.

You say that you've got a string but show an example with an array.
Assuming you really have a string in input you may try [explode() function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to explode it to an array of objects.

Then having a real Array [in_array() function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) will do the job.

```
$resultString = "12 13 17 26";
$resultArray = explode(" ", $resultString);
if (in_array("13", $resultArray)) {
    echo "found";
} else {
    echo "not found";
}
```